# Moving/migrating application from Homestead to Valet

Tags: laravel, homestead, laravel-valet

I have a Laravel application running on Homestead. I'm trying to migrate this to using valet instead.

What I have done.

1. Removed the IP from the hosts file
2. Removed the pointer in the homstead.yaml
3. Ran vagrant reload --provision
4. Ran valet restart

Still, valet does not seem to do the correct routing. It does not serve the directory.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Can you give us more pointers? Like what is the URL you are using, do other valet sites work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved by restarting my computer.